# Rails: Devise - Invalid authenticity token on action from subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I work on an application which is scaled across multiple subdomains. So I configured devise, which I use for authentication, to authenticate users across all these subdomains.

I have no problem signing in or signing up, but when I try to destroy either a users session or the entire account, I get the following error:

> ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in Users::RegistrationsController#destroy
>   ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

The corresponding links:

```
= linkt_to(registration_url(current_user), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete) do ...
= linkt_to(destroy_user_session_url, :method => :delete) do ...
```

I have set in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app_session', domain: :all, tld_length: 2
```

Answer (score -2):

Add the following in the /initializers/session_store.rb

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :my_cookie_store, domain: :all
```

restart the server

Comment: I already have set this (`Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app_session', domain: :all, tld_length: 2`) in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`.

Comment: remove tld_length & then test